# Unable to install php 5.6 in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: php, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to install php5.6 into my ubuntu 14.04 server.
Using following link
https://tecadmin.net/install-php5-on-ubuntu/

Using following Commands.

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y php5.6
```

but getting following error.

1. "Unable to locate package php5.6"
2. "Couldn't find ant package by regex'php5.6' "

Please provide solution.

Comment: Are you sure that you still want to run a server that is out of support? Even LTS support ended in April 2019. You cannot expect anyone to still support this. Also, security support for PHP 5.6 ended in 2018

Answer (score -2):

It was removed from repository. You can`t install it from ondrej/php repository 
[Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusty), PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0 going away](https://www.patreon.com/posts/ubuntu-14-04-php-22093917) See also: [Ubuntu 14.04 LTS reached end-of-life](https://www.patreon.com/posts/ubuntu-14-04-lts-26560500)

Comment: Hi.. Please provide links or context.. Here is a link to how to write a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer